# "let" in Racket Matacircular Evaluator

Tags: scheme, racket, interpreter

I'm writing a metacircular evaluator in Racket and I'm having trouble with creating a syntactic abstraction for a let expression. I'm trying to create code for the body of a let, so essentially,`(expand-let '(((a 1) (b 2)) (+ a b)))`
should produce `'((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 1 2)`

I know I need to recurse through the bindings until the expression (+ a b) is reached, but I'm unclear on how to ask in Racket if the car of a list is a +, -, *, etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to check which operation is used anyway?

Comment: I need to create a list that contains a list of keys (a b), the expression, and the values. The problem is that there can be a varying number of bindings passed in and the operation in the expression can vary.

Comment: In a let `(let ((x y) (y z) ...) expression)` the bindings are in their own a-list. Thus you don't recurse until you hit an expression you recurse until you hit the end of the a-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. Here's my implementation of `expand-let`:

```
(define (expand-let form)
  (define bindings (car form))
  `((lambda ,(map car bindings) ,@(cdr form))
    ,@(map cadr bindings)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to ask Racket if the `car` of a list is a `+`, `-`, `*`, etc. The `expand-lambda` function can be defined as follows:

```lisp
(define (expand-lambda expr)
    (let* ((pairs (car expr))
           (body  (cdr expr))
           (keys  (map car pairs))
           (vals  (map cadr pairs)))
    (cons (cons 'lambda (cons keys body)) vals)))
```

Hope that helps.